# Android database openOrCreate() error

Tags: android, sqlite

I have two classes, both are not activity, one is to perform database operation and one is to forward the values as mediator class. DataBase class calling openOrCreateDataBase method from a 3rd Connectivity class.

```
    contextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(sqlDBName, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```

but here since this class is not activity, i am unable to pass parameter of ContextWrapper. Is there any other way to open database. I have tried,

```
    sqLiteDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, factory, flags);
    sqLiteDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(file, factory);
```

But these not working for me.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a database without Context. This is one of the thing context exists for: it allows you to access shared preferences, database and so on.

Comment: thanks for reply vladimir. Is there any way to get ContextWrapper of previously called activity, in which this operations are being performed.

Comment: What do you mean by previously called? Anyway, you call your DataBase code from nowhere. You call it from activity or a service, so you always have a context. Just pass a reference of activity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way. In the constructor of the db wrapper class you can add the ContextWrapper as a parameter and call it, like this:

```
public ctor(ContextWrapper wrapper) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = wrapper.openOrCreateDatabase("myDB", wrapper.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    }
```